# How can I use the sed command to replace a fixed pattern?

Tags: unix

I am trying to replace a fixed pattern with another pattern. The pattern which needs to be replaced is:

```
{
        "field_name": "genDtl.schmNature",
        "data_type": "tbaFlagType","fld_size": "0","bspc": "",
            "type": "hardcoded",
            "value": "N",
            "neg_value": "",
            "desc": "",
            "is_fetch_input": "N",
        },
```

The resulting pattern should be:

```
{
        "field_name": "genDtl.schmNature",
        "data_type": "tbaFlagType","fld_size": "0","bspc": "",
            "type": "hardcoded",
            "value": "N",
            "neg_value": "",
            "desc": "",
            "is_fetch_input": "N",
        },
        {
        "field_name": "genDtl.autoClsOfZeroBalAcctFlg",
        "data_type": "tbaFlagType","fld_size": "0","bspc": "",
            "type": "hardcoded",
            "value": "Y",
            "neg_value": "",
            "desc": "",
            "is_fetch_input": "N",
        },
```

How can I use the `sed` command to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/your-long-pattern/&the-additional-text/' inputfile
```

The ampersand repeats the found string.

You might also be able to use:

```
sed 's/\({ "field_name": "\)\(genDtl.schmNature\)\(", "data_type": "tbaFlagType","fld_size": "0","bspc": "", "type": "hardcoded", "value": "\)\(N\)\(", "neg_value": "", "desc": "", "is_fetch_input": "N", },\)/\1\2\3\4\5\1genDtl.autoClsOfZeroBalAcctFlg\3Y\5/' inputfile
```

(untested)

Comment: For large substitutions like this, I suggest using an external sed script file with the -e flag, e.g. sed -e  foo.sed <infile > outfile. Registers are fine or you can apply multiple "s" commands in the sed file to each line.

Comment: @kmarsh: `-e` is for an in-line script. I think you mean `-f` which takes a filename. By "registers" do you mean capture groups/back references?

Comment: Yes, I meant -f. The term "Registers" can be found in some families of man pages, on GNU systems do "info regex" and search for registers, in section 7.1.8 on my Linux system.